# SAS Enterprise Guide, add columns to one table with values from another

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have a date table I make in a program with some calculated dates. There are 4 columns, with one row of dates.

```
referenceDate  |  startTwoMonth  |  startThreeMonth  |  startYear
-----------------------------------------------------------------
31Oct2015      |  01Sep2015      |  01Aug2015        |  01Nov2015
```

I would like to add these 4 columns to another table with many rows, and have these 4 date values occur in every row. (It makes it easier to do filtering later in the project.)

Currently, with a Query Builder step on my main data table, I use Add Tables to add the second date table above. Query builder says it cannot find a suitable join condition, which is correct, there isn't any. In the table list on the left, I grab all of the columns from the data table and the date table and put them into the Select Data area on the right. When I run the query, it gives me the output I want, but I get an error that the tables aren't joined and it could cause serious performance problems.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is it an error or a warning? What you're looking for is called a cross join/cartesian product and SAS does generate a warning but I thought it still executed and created a table.

Comment: It is just a warning, and it works quickly enough. I was just curious if there was a better way to do it without the warning.

Comment: I don't think there is...there may be a way to suppress the warning or you could use a program step with code that wouldn't generate the warning if that's an issue.

Comment: I didn't read your question carefully. I think adding calculated fields may be a better solution. See a post tagged SAS from yesterday about how to calculate dates automatically based on current or run date.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a data step that accomplishes the same thing:

```
data want;
set sashelp.class;
if _n_=1 then set single_row;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add in the values as calculated columns in an SQL step.

For the calculation, you would have something like `'32oct2015'd` then give it a name of referenceDate.

To clarify, you're basically moving the logic from the reference table into the 'main' table.